# Proving/deciding concavity of a function of two variables

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to formally prove that the function $f(x,y) = \frac{(c+1)e^{-x}(xe^{x+y}+y)}{(c+2)(e^{x+y}-1)+e^y} $ is concave ($ c>2$ is a constant, and both $x,\, y \in \mathbf{R_+}$).

Plots of the function indicate it to be concave. Both the numerator and the denominator are convex and positive. But approaching $f(x,y)$ as a ratio of two convex functions (with different gradients) didn't help in my attempts towards a concavity proof.
Useful suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Here is a plot of the function:
[image: Apparent concavity of f(x,y)]

Comment: You'll have to compute the Hessian and verify it is negative semidefinite for all $x,y$, I suspect. I see no easy way out of that. But I'm going to be honest: I'll bet it's not actually concave. It might look it along certain directions, but it has to be convex along *all* lines.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I did compute the Hessian using Mathematica, but that turns out to be too bloated to decide negative semi-definiteness. 
Just added a plot of the function, it doesn't look convex at all.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke: it has to look *concave* along all lines in order for it to actually be concave. I am not convinced that it remains concave for all $x,y$.

Comment: I would consider looking along lines like $x=a-y$ for some values of $a$, and $x\in[0,a]$.

Comment: Your insight has paid off, Michael. I substituted $x$ with $a-y$ and plotted the transformed single variable function against $x$ keeping $x \in [0, a]$. Then trying with different values for the positive constant $a$, it turns out that the line no longer remains concave when $a \gtrapprox  2$ (while remains quasi-concave, apparently). I would accept it as an answer at this point, as it theoretically settles it (thanks).
Now, as for the practical context, I am interested in and around the crest. Any ideas as to how to characterize $x,y$ that keep close to the crest?